# Woocommerce Admin Orders hook to limit number or total orders displayed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for an add_filter or add_action that I could put in functions.php to limit the amount of queried or cached results in the orders admin edit page (shop_order).

We currently have about 15,000 orders and the queries are taking 20 seconds or more to load. Limiting the results to last 1000 or 2000 would suffice.

Transients have been deleted, database optimized. usual culprits identified. But I am not arrogant enough to know all so any suggestions are welcome including modifying the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quick brainstorming, but maybe this should help:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limitShopOrders' );

function limitShopOrders ( $query ) {

if ( is_admin() and $query->is_main_query() and $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'shop_order' ) {

$query->set( 'posts_per_page' => 1000 );
$query->set( 'no_found_rows' => true );

}

}
```

Interesting and important is **no_found_rows** - you can read about it here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/181553

Comment: Thanks for this. However it seems to throw an error. Maybe because posts_per_page etc should be set in an array?

Comment: ok, I found the issue: $query->set( 'posts_per_page' , '1000' ); I am correcting your answer and accepting as solution. Thank you.